# Reset/Delete the value of a field with node_save()

Tags: entities

I have a content type with a `field_FOO` of type `text`. I have a procedure that check which nodes have this `field_FOO` without value (`$node->field_FOO == array()` ), extract 1 at random, make some operations, set a value for this field (`field_FOO[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'bar'`) and save the node.

Now for 10.000+ nodes I need to delete this value but I don't want to do a `node_load`, empty `field_FOO`, `node_save` because for every `node_save` Drupal change the changed date associated with that nodes.

So, how can I "**delete**" the value of a field without use `node_save()`? If I delete the entry from `field_data_field_FOO` table I risk a site down ?

In the `field_data_field_FOO` table there is a "deleted" column. If I set it to 1, at the next `hook_cron()` that fields are deleted without a site down ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do by changing the database entry then you need to check key constraints for the field table and also you need to remove its dependency from the parent table.